# How to delete slackbot reminder that was created by other person?

Tags: bots, slack

There is slack private channel with slackbot reminder. It was created by person doesn't work at our company anymore. How can i delete this noisy slackbot reminder??

Comment: how you tried deactivating the account of the former employee? Should also disable the reminder.

Comment: this should be moved to webapps.SE or SuperUser IMHO

Answer (score 339, accepted):

You can accomplish this by typing `/remind list` into the private channel's message box.

You'll then see a list of all active reminders in the channel along with links to `Delete` them.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks. That's works for personal bots as well.

Comment: @iGbanam this works for me as well. What do you see when you type in that particular command?

Comment: I don't think I had the right authorization to delete the reminder

Comment: It won't work if you're part of a group message. They say they can't find a list for you.

Comment: This won't work if you didn't create the reminder for the channel.  You should be able to 'kick the bot out' and then add a new one if needed.  Check Slack documentation for how to kick out a bot- not linking here because it has changed a few times.